# Closed form of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am so terrible at finding a closed form of a given sequence. Please help me on the following sequence:

$$
f(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{8}x-\frac{7}{128}x^2-\frac{35}{1024}x^3-\frac{805}{32768}x^4-\frac{4991}{262144}x^5-\frac{64883}{4194304}x^6-\frac{435643}{33554432}x^7+..
$$

I realize there are powers of 2 in the denominator but I can not relate the numbers in the whole series.

thanks.

Comment: That's not a sequence. That's a function of $x$.

Comment: Not a sequence, a (power) series.

Comment: Then my question becomes; is there a way to find $$a_{n}$$ in terms of $$n$$?

Comment: @Yakup Given only finitely many terms it is impossible.

Comment: And how/where did this series appear?

Comment: I needed to find the critical point of this function by the ratio method. as best as I can

Comment: @Yakup: You can merge your current account with the one you used to post this question originally by doing this: `From any page footer -> 'contact us' >> 'Merge user profiles'`

Comment: I didn't get a hit in oeis for your numerators but your denominators show up in as [A061549](http://oeis.org/A061549). One of the notes is that the sequence is the sequence of demoninators of the power series of $1/(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})$. Which is presumably the original context for the problem.

Comment: It is difficult without an expression for the general term. True, the denominators are powers of $2,$ but $3,7,10,15,18,22,25$ doesn't have obvious structure. Neither do the numerators $1,7,7\cdot 5, 7\cdot5\cdot3,7\cdot 713?$

Answer (score 5):

By inspection, this is the power series for $f(x)=\sqrt[8]{1-x}$ around $x=0$.  So, the coefficient of $x^n$ will be $(-1)^n \binom{1/8}{n}$.